# How do I change the way objects are displayed?

Tags: ruby, inspect

In this script, I take user input, pass it to an object, and then push that object into an array. I then iterate over that array:

```
objects_array = Array.new

class Object
  def initialize(fname)
    @first_name = fname
  end
end

fname = gets.chomp
user_first = Object.new(fname)
objects_array <<  user_first
objects_array.each {|x| print x}
```

I gave the input `"Tyler"` from the terminal, and the results that I am expecting is:

```
Tyler
```

but I do not retrieve those results. Instead of the object string, I receive the memory location:

```
#<Object:0x26f00b8>
```

I am having trouble referencing the information of an object that is located in an array. What do I need to change to receive the information of the object in the array rather than the memory location?

Comment: Why would you think that printing the object particularly prints its `@first_name`? What if you had `@foo = "foo"; @bar = "bar"; @baz = "baz"; @first_name = fname` in your definition? Should it print `"foo"`? Or `"bar"`? or `"foo bar"`, or ... Which one? Or if you had an object that doesn't have the instance variable `@first_name`, then should it print nothing?

Answer (score 8):

Ruby cannot print an Object (present as a string) in a nice way without a proper `to_s` method. If there is no `to_s` method then Ruby's fallback is an internal method that just takes the class name and the object id.

You need to add a `to_s` method to your model:

```
class Object
  def initialize(fname)
    @first_name = fname
  end 

  def to_s
    @first_name
  end
end
```